# Accessing passed binding in template

Tags: angular

I tried creating a component using Angular 2. It works fine but I'm not really sure how to pass a value as binding.
Here is the code:

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app/grid.htm',
      bindings:{
          info:'=info'
      }
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {
          this.items = [
                { id: 1, name: 'Roy', age: 25 },
                { id: 2, name: 'James', age: 30 }
            ];
      }
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

From the view part I'm passing in the items in the constructor as :

```
<my-app info="items">Loading...</my-app>
```

But I'm not able to access it in the template `templateUrl: './app/grid.htm',`

Here is the template code:

```
<tr *ngFor='#item of info'>
                    <td>
                        <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                        <span>{{ item.age }}</span>
                    </td>
 </tr>
```

But it's not working. Can any one point out what may be wrong ??

Answer (score 1):

`@Input()` is currently not supported on the root component (`AppComponent`).

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858

As a workaround you can use

```
.Class({
  constructor: [ ElementRef, function(ref) {
    ref.nativeElement.getAttribute('mydata');
  }]
});
```

In your HTML file:

```
<my-app mydata="Some sample data">
  loading...
</my-app>
```

(allows only String)

But in your case, you don't need to have an `info` attribute. Since your data are loaded within the component and set into one of its properties, you can use them directly within your `ngFor`:

```
<tr *ngFor='#item of items'>
  (...)
</tr>
```

**Edit**

You can pass the data through an input element from the parent component (`<display [data]="items"></display>`), as described below:

```
App.DisplayComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'display',
      inputs: [ 'data' ],
      template: '<div>' +
        '  <tr *ngFor="#item of data">' +
        '    <td>' +
        '      <span>{{ item.name }}</span>' +
        '    </td>' +
        '    <td>' +
        '      <span>{{ item.age }}</span> ' +
        '    </td>' +
        '  </tr>' +
        '</div>'
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function() {}
    });

App.AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<display [data]="items"></display>',
      directives: [App.DisplayComponent]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function() {
          this.items = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Roy', age: 25 },
            { id: 2, name: 'James', age: 30 }
          ];
        }
    });
```

Here is a sample plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ki6e9KgsPaiHIxfhKH3E?p=preview.

Comment: may I know how `ref.nativeElement.getAttribute('mydata')` will understand that he need to fetch `mydata` from `this.items`, rather than taking it from `attribute`?

Comment: How would I pass data loaded outside component to the component using attributes ?